# Convert binary tree to doubly linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list, tree

The code works and I get the results I want. Please comment about complexity, a shorter way of implementing the solution, and advice for better unit tests.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class BinaryTreeToList
    {
        public BinaryTreeToList()
        {


        }   

        public DoubleLinkedListNode ConvertTreeToDoubleLinkedListNode(TreeNode root)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            DoubleLinkedListNode res = new DoubleLinkedListNode();
            res.Index = root.Index;
            if (root.Left != null)
            {
                var newNode = ConvertTreeToDoubleLinkedListNode(root.Left);
                newNode.Previous = res;
                res.Next = newNode;
            }
            if (root.Right != null)
            {
                if (res.Next == null)
                {
                    var newNode = ConvertTreeToDoubleLinkedListNode(root.Right);
                    newNode.Previous = res;
                    res.Next = newNode;
                }
                else if (res.Next.Next == null)
                {

                    var newNode = ConvertTreeToDoubleLinkedListNode(root.Right);
                    newNode.Previous = res.Next;
                    res.Next.Next = newNode;

                }
                else
                {
                    DoubleLinkedListNode temp = res;
                    while (temp.Next != null)
                    {
                        temp = temp.Next;
                    }
                    var newNode =  ConvertTreeToDoubleLinkedListNode(root.Right);
                    newNode.Previous = temp;
                    temp.Next = newNode;

                }
            }
            return res;
        }
    }

    public class DoubleLinkedListNode
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public DoubleLinkedListNode Next { get; set; }
        public DoubleLinkedListNode Previous { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ConsoleApplication2;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BinaryTreeConvertToList
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            BinaryTreeToList binaryTreeToList = new BinaryTreeToList();
            //            0 
            //        2         4
            //     6    8          10
            TreeNode root = new TreeNode(0);
            root.Left = new TreeNode(2);
            root.Right = new TreeNode(4);
            root.Left.Left = new TreeNode(6);
            root.Left.Right = new TreeNode(8);
            root.Right.Right = new TreeNode(10);

            var res1 = binaryTreeToList.ConvertTreeToDoubleLinkedListNode(root);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, res1);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, res1.Next);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Naming**

- I personally prefer a class named `Convert` for such a task. This would also be more natural because the NET provided converting methods live in a `Convert` class too.
- to be consistent with the NET naming I also would prefer the method be named `ToDoubleLinkedListNode()`
- instead of shortening the name of the node to be returned to `res`, name it `convertedNode`
- you should name the node which is returned by the recursive calls `leftNode` or `rightNode`.

**General**

- by extracting the search for the last `Next` node which is `not null` to a separate method, the `if..else if..else` can be removed.
- if you use a guard claus for `root.Right == null` you save horizontal spacing.
- the method should be static, because it doesn't depend on any internal state of the class itself. This makes the `constructor` obsolete.

**Refactoring**

After all for above is applied the refactored code looks like

```
public class Convert
{
    public DoubleLinkedListNode ToDoubleLinkedListNode(TreeNode root)
    {
        if (root == null) { return null; }

        DoubleLinkedListNode convertedNode = new DoubleLinkedListNode { Index = root.Index };

        if (root.Left != null)
        {
            var leftNode = ToDoubleLinkedListNode(root.Left);
            leftNode.Previous = convertedNode;
            convertedNode.Next = leftNode;
        }

        if (root.Right == null) { return convertedNode; }

        var rightNode = ToDoubleLinkedListNode(root.Right);

        DoubleLinkedListNode lastNextNode = FindLastNextNode(convertedNode);
        rightNode.Previous = lastNextNode;
        lastNextNode.Next = rightNode;

        return convertedNode;
    }
    private static DoubleLinkedListNode FindLastNextNode(DoubleLinkedListNode node)
    {
        while (node.Next != null)
        {
            node = node.Next;
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```